# Smooth Voicing Leading Explanation

Tags: piano, midi, voice-leading

I know what smooth voice leading is, but I'm writing an OS X app that teaches my piano students how to play chords in a gamified way.

Just before they play the first level where they have to play chords with smooth voice leading, I am going to have a tutorial. I need it to have as few words as possible. No one likes to read a lot while playing a "game". I'm really struggling to find a concise way of explaining this concept though. Attached to this question is how I created the initial tutorial for playing the very first "level" (if you can call it that). It's just a series of images that teaches the user what to do. This is the sort of design I'm going for.

What I'm looking for is a set of concise steps to explaining this concept. The user needs to connect from chord to chord so that the top note does not jump (moves by a semitone or tone above/below at most). I hope this is not off topic.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. Three steps:

- 1.) Spell each chord
- 2.) Keep shared notes between chords.
- 3.) Move other notes the least amount of distance possible to spell next chord.